# vscode unable to find header file in c

Tags: c

I have a program file and when I run that is vs code I get

```
fatal error: header_file.h: No such file or directory
```

even if the file is in its directory, I have tied to add the path in c_cpp_properties.json in .vscode file still the same

this is my c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "sdk/include/sdk_inc/"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang-15",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

I am using vscode in ubuntu 22.04

task.json

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "--include-directory=sdk/include/sdk_inc"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

and i notices there is a makefile too when I try the command make it gives me this error

`/bin/sh: 1: mips-linux-uclibc-gnu-gcc: not found`

i am trying to run gos_sdk_demo.c file

and header files are in sdk>include>sd_inc

[image: photo]

and this is the error
[image]

i don't know if it is relative or not

when I try to use "make" command I get this
[image]

Comment: Is `"sdk/..."` supposed to be an absolute path? Did you miss leading `/`?Or is it supposed to be in workspace folder?

Comment: Why "${workspaceFolder}/**" instead of "${workspaceFolder}"

Comment: @Gerhardh with or without  /  it shows the same error, if you want i will upload the directory structure

Comment: @stark i have just tried without  /**  it shows same error what can I do next

Comment: Oh, I misread the error message. The configuration file you show is for VS Code to find headers. That doesn't matter for the compiler. The error message seems to come from the compiler. You musst add the include folders via `-I` command line argument in your tasks.json file.

Comment: @Gerhardh i did not understand how to do it

Comment: @Gerhardh hey i have added task.json file just tell me where to add that

Comment: Also with tasks.json, my first comment is valid: Is that an absolut path? Where is the file located that is not found by the compiler (Full path)? Where is your workplace folder where you call the compiler?

Comment: @Gerhardh i even tried this sdk/include/sdk_inc/gos_ipc_sdk.h  that did not work

Comment: and i notices there is a makefile too when I try the command make it gives me this error 
/bin/sh: 1: mips-linux-uclibc-gnu-gcc: not found

Comment: How are you including the header?

Comment: @Randommm headers are in the same folder and I am adding its path in c_cpp_properties.json file too

Comment: But how have you done the include in the file(s)?

Comment: Again: What is the full path of the header file? In which folder do you try to build? And as Randommm asked: How do you include the header in your code? If you don't answer the questions, we cannot help

Comment: @Gerhardh the program is inside a folder called demo and when I compile it, it creates a folder called output I think it that's the build file, and the header files are in a folder called SDK

Comment: Please show it, don't describe it. And "a folder called SDK" is not a full path. What output does VSCode when you compile? Full output including command lines...

Comment: @Gerhardh nailed the issue with his first comment. Where in the compiler string shown in the error message do you see `-Isdk/include/sdk_inc`? It's not there. Further your `c_cpp_properties.json` says `"compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang-15",`, but your compile string uses `gcc`? Which is it? Solve those two problems and this compiler error will go away. **Tip -** when an IDE isn't doing what you think it should, open an `x-term` and switch to the directory containing your code and then build manually from the command line. In this case using `gcc ... -Isdk/include/sdk_inc ...` and check.

Answer (score 0):

I added `-I./inc` to the `arg` in `task.json` and it worked.
In addition in the task, I added a path to all cpp code as `${fileDirname}\\src\\*.cpp`